# SQL Server get a certain row value as a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-science

I have a table like this one:

```
|  machine  |  type  |    value  |  id  |
+-----------+--------+-----------+------+
|     1     |   a    |     0.34  |   1  |
|     1     |   b    |     0.23  |   2  |
|     1     |   b    |     0.26  |   3  |
|     1     |   b    |     0.35  |   4  |
|     1     |   a    |     0.15  |   5  |
|     1     |   b    |     0.45  |   6  |
|     1     |   b    |     0.55  |   7  |
```

And I would like to obtain a table with the row with type "a" as column (id is not relevant in this case). For example:

```
|  machine  |  value | value_col |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|     1     |   0.23 |  0.34     |
|     1     |   0.26 |  0.34     |
|     1     |   0.35 |  0.34     |
|     1     |   0.45 |  0.15     |
|     1     |   0.55 |  0.15     |
```

I tried the SQL Server pivot function but I cannot obtain the desired result.

Comment: How are you generating the `value` and `value_col` columns; what's the query you've written that's not working.

Comment: what's the logic here? How IDs 2, 3 and 4 of type b are matched with ID 1 of type a and 6,7 of b with 5 of a .... You should explain the logic of this matching...

Comment: Hi Tom, 
You question is missing some content, for instance, if you want to pivot your dataset over the "type" values, what is the aggregation (computation)  that you want to make? Would you like for instance to count the number of machines of type 'a' ? Or would you like to make a sum,average, etc... over the 'value' column.
Your question is missing content, either amend it or provide us with a SQL query to be able to help you.

Comment: The ID are not relevant so i don't want to select it. This table contains a value (type b) and a threshold value (type a). Everytime the threshold value change on the machine, it will be recorded in the table. But i would like to run a query that contains all this information at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CROSS APPLY()` to obtain the last `a` value

```
select t.machine, t.value, v.value_col
from   tbl t
       cross apply
       (
           select top 1 value_col = value
           from   tbl x
           where  x.id < t.id
           and    x.type = 'a'
           order by id desc
       ) v
where  t.type = 'b'
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dbdf3fd9483e90be141c2b3b3d3e39f6)

Comment: Certainly more concise than using analytic functions.  Would be interested to profile performance of a correlated-sub-query on large datasets *(where the nature of analytic functions **may** have an advantage)*.

Comment: To partition by `machine` this would have `and x.machine = t.machine` in the correlated sub-query.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done in three steps, which makes me feel there are cleaner ways (but that I can't think of them)

1. create an identifier to relate all rows which should share an `a` value
2. use a window function to copy that `a` value to the rest of the partition
3. filter to include only the `b` rows

For example...

```
WITH
  a_partitioned AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type='a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY machine ORDER BY id)  AS a_partition
  FROM
    your_table
),
  a_value_spread AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'a' THEN value END) OVER (PARTITION BY machine, a_partition)  AS a_value
  FROM
    a_partitioned 
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  a_value_spread
WHERE
  type = 'b'
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9037c0d3e6d46e05ecbcfdd3777808cd

***EDIT***

Here's my ***REALLY*** superficial attempt to experiment with which answer might have the lowest processing overheads...

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5433abb2181ff92be72cf9247d3ff0b0

In the correlated sub-query version, the scan of the data is 4% of the total cost

- So, the whole query 'costs' ~20 index scans

In the analytic function version, the scan of the data is 12% of the total cost

- So, the whole query 'costs' ~8.3 index scans

It's a very small data set though, and a very arbitrarily constructed data-set.

- I'd run an actual profiler against your actual data
- ***IF*** performance matters

(If the correlated sub-query approach is 'fast enough', definitely use that.)

Comment: I found this analysis very useful to optimize my query, thank you!

Comment: while checking on the logical reads and the scan count, the cross apply version gets less logical reads than the analytical function version, which is a good thing when considering performance. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=85ba1976beb8b512c310ff4c98885582